# Chemical change - decomposing single element?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

If I had a molecule of a single element such as atmospheric oxygen O2, and I added energy to decompose it into two separate oxygen atoms (i.e. O2 + ENERGY –– 2 O ) is this a chemical or physical change?

Comment: Please see my response on chemical and physical changes https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131474/why-is-solubility-often-listed-as-a-chemical-property-isnt-the-action-of-disso/131477#131477

Comment: At an elementary level, your decomposition of O2 molecule into O atoms is a chemical change.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I assumed that this was a chemical reaction because the chemical formula is changing. It does seem the distinction between physical and chemical changes can get a bit nebulous though.

Comment: Yes and in the long term this labeling is useless.

Comment: Something like physical and chemical "change" has only notion in some introductory textbooks. Chemical *reaction* is the important term.

Answer (score 5):

**It is a chemical change**

The aspect of this that is probably confusing you is that both the product and the result in the case of an element are still a form of the element.

But elements can exist in different chemical forms and moving between them is still a chemical process. A relevant example is the reaction occurring mostly in the upper atmosphere that converts dioxygen (O<sub>2</sub>) to ozone (O<sub>3</sub>). This is a specific example of what happens when you add energy (in this case from UV light) to an oxygen molecule in the presence of other oxygen molecules: the split-apart oxygen atoms react to form ozone (which is more stable than a free oxygen atom). This is clearly a *chemical* change as the molecular structure is different, though ozone is still elementary oxygen so the *element* has not changed.